# 2 Future methods called: how to distinguish which one has data

Tags: flutter

There are two methods called in Future.wait. What is a way to distinguish which one has data... or should I construct below code in different way...

```
child: FutureBuilder<List<Object>>(
          future: Future.wait([postsFuture, postsFutureListOfDiets]),
          builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<List<dynamic>> snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
              print('>>>> waiting <<<<');
              return const CircularProgressIndicator(
                backgroundColor: Colors.black,
                valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.green)
              );
            } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
              print('>>>> has data <<<<');
              List posts = snapshot.data![0]??[];
              List postsListOfDiets = snapshot.data![1]??[];

              if(posts.isEmpty){
                print('>>>> no data[0] <<<<');
                return const Text("No data...");
              } else if(postsListOfDiets.isEmpty){
                print('>>>> no data[1] <<<<');
                return const Text("No data...");
              } else if(postsListOfDiets.isNotEmpty){   // always true
                print('>>>> call buildPostsListOfDiets <<<<');
                return buildPostsListOfDiets(snapshot.data![1]);
              } else {
                print('>>>> call buildPosts <<<<');     //never executed
                return buildPosts(snapshot.data![0]);
              }
            } else {
              return const Text("No data...");
            }
            }
          ),
```

---

UPDATE 1

Please look at more code below. If you think this can be done in better way, please advice. I did try with two futures, but I got error message. Could you please  describe how to use two futures separately in this case? Sorry for such a basic question, but I have very little experience with flutter.

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey[300],
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton.extended(
        onPressed: () {

          showModalBottomSheet(
            isScrollControlled: true,
            context: context,
            builder: ((context) {
              return Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom),
                child: SizedBox(
                height: 400,

                  child: DropdownButtonFormField(
                    ...  
                      );
                    },
                    icon: const Icon(
                      Icons.arrow_drop_down_circle,
                      color: Colors.blue,
                    ),
                    dropdownColor: Colors.grey[200],
                    decoration: const InputDecoration(
                      labelText: "Some text",
                      prefixIcon: Icon(
                        Icons.accessibility_new_rounded,
                        color: Colors.blue,
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
                ),
              );
            })
          );
        },
        icon: const Icon(Icons.add),
        label: const Text('Some text'),
      ),
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.grey[900],
        title: const Text('Some text'),
        actions: [
          IconButton(
            onPressed: signUserOut,
            icon: const Icon(Icons.logout),
          )
        ],
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: FutureBuilder<List<Object>>(
          future: Future.wait([postsFuture, postsFutureListOfDiets]),
          builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<List<dynamic>> snapshot) {
               
              ...

            }
          ),
        ),
    );
  }
```

Then buildPosts comes:

```
  Widget buildPosts(List<Post> posts) {
    return ListView.builder(
          itemCount: posts.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            print('>>>> 2 <<<<');
            final post = posts[index];
            final List<ChartData> chartData = [
              ChartData('', post.proc!.toDouble(), Colors.green),
              ChartData('', (100.toDouble() - post.proc!.toDouble()), Colors.black),
            ];
            return GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                loadListDetails(post.id!, post.lista!);
              },
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.white,
                margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5, horizontal: 0),
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5, horizontal: 15),
                
               ....
```

and the buildPostsListOfDiets code:

```
  Widget buildPostsListOfDiets(List<PostListOfDiets> posts) {
    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton.extended(
            onPressed: () {
            
            showModalBottomSheet(
                isScrollControlled: true,
                context: context,
                builder: ((context) {
                  return Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom),
                    child: SizedBox(
                        height: 400,
                        child: DropdownButtonFormField(

                            ...
                  
                        )
                    ),
                  );
                })
            );
          },
          icon: const Icon(Icons.add),
          label: const Text('Dodaj listę'),
        )
      );
  }
```

Comment: What's the purpose of this? Why don't you use separate futures?

Comment: I would like to get data from API: two queries: one for list of items and second one once a button is tapped with another ListOfDiets.

Comment: if two views are involved, would it be easier to use two futures separately? first view future of the list of items, second view future for item details.

Comment: I have updated post with some additional code that describes what I want to do. Could you please advice on how to use two futures instead in my case? If you could write a basic skeleton of it would be great. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Do this: this will work if the data expected is a list

```
FutureBuilder<List<Object>>(
          future: Future.wait([postsFuture, postsFutureListOfDiets]),
          builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<List<dynamic>> snapshot) {
             ...
            //else if (snapshot.hasData) {} <== no need of this any more
            ...
            //check if data in index 0 has items
            else if(snapshot.data![0].length >= 1){
            //return your widget
           }else if(snapshot.data![1].length >= 1)
          ),
```

Or you could combine for simplicity

```
FutureBuilder<List<Object>>(
          future: Future.wait([postsFuture, postsFutureListOfDiets]),
          builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<List<dynamic>> snapshot) {
            ...
            //check if data in index 0 has items
             if(snapshot.hasData && snapshot.data![0].length >= 1){
            //return your widget
           }else if(snapshot.hasData &&snapshot.data![1].length >= 1)
          ),
```

Comment: it does not work. I cannot find snapshot.data![0].length

Comment: Then it mean you have no items in the list

Comment: If `snapshot.data` is a list then you use`.length`